# How to pop a Node on a stack without getting a NPE

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, stack

This is a pop method for a linked list implementation of a stack.

This method will throw a NPE when the "number of pops" is equal to the "size of the linked list".

Example:

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.push("A");
        list.push("B");
        list.push("C");

        System.out.println(list.pop().getElement());
        System.out.println(list.pop().getElement());
        // the below code list.pop will have a null value.
        System.out.println(list.pop().getElement());
        System.out.println(list.pop().getElement());

public boolean isEmpty()
{
        return head == null;
}

public Node pop()
{

                if( !isEmpty())
                {
                    head = head.getNext();
                    size--;
                }
                else if(isEmpty())
                {
                    System.out.println("empty stack");

                }

                 return  head;

}
```

My solution was to re-write like this but now there is duplicated code for return head which I have no idea to fix. Any guidance on this issue would help.

```
 public Node pop()
 {

                if(head != null)
                {
                    return head;
                }
                if( !isEmpty())
                {
                    head = head.getNext();
                    size--;
                }
                else if(isEmpty())
                {
                    System.out.println("empty stack");

                }

                 return  head;

 }
```

Another question: Not sure, should I call the variable head(a linked list concept) or top(a stack concept)? Please answer this question as well.

My argument for those who might be wondering why I am returning a node object that will be deleted later on: My textbook says pop means I need to return the popped node as well as remove it from the linked list instead of just removing it.

Comment: Why you are trying to do the stack logic from beginning,why not to use java one

Comment: I have to implement my own to learn data structures more deeply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first implementation:

```
public Node pop()
{
    if( !isEmpty())
    {
        head = head.getNext();
        size--;
    }
    else if(isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("empty stack");

    }

     return  head;

}
```

Imagine your list is `5->6->7->null`.

The head points to `5`. This list is not empty. So you do the `head = head.getNext()`, now the head points to 6. And then you return `head`, which is `6`.

So your error is that you skipped the first element without returning it. What you should do is keep a reference to the current head, advance the head, and then return the reference that you saved - not the new `head`.

---

In your second implementation:

```
public Node pop()
 {
    if(head != null)
    {
        return head;
    }
    if( !isEmpty())
    {
        head = head.getNext();
        size--;
    }
    else if(isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("empty stack");

    }

     return  head;

 }
```

If the head is not null, you just return, without advancing it. As soon as you use `return`, nothing else is going to be done in the method.

---

Note: It would be better, instead of returning a node, to return the same type that you `push`. Returning a `Node` gives the user dangerous access to your linked list. You should be returning the actual element instead.

Comment: Good point! I changed my method to return to element now and I made sure to store head as a temp to return the temp! Great help!

Answer (score 0):

In method `pop`, you are not returning `head`, you are returning `head.getNext()`.

So change your logic. You can try this:

In method `pop`

```
Node tem = head;
if( !isEmpty())
    {
        head = head.getNext();
        size--;
    }
    else // no need to check head again
    {
        System.out.println("empty stack");

     }

     return  tem;
```